# Office 365 App Only Auth MVC c#

Tags: c#, authentication, model-view-controller, office365

I have currently implemented the code into my app from https://github.com/mattleib/o365api-as-apponly-webapp

It all works when clicking sign up, Auth's the account properly and returns to the same Page and allows me to load the calendar events.

My issue is that i need this to be persistent across the entire app as my aim is to do the following.

- Administrator on initial login and or app start up, Auth's the app to Office 365.
- When a user logs in they have a link to a page that will display the calendar that is configured for the page, a Resource.

Im assuming i need to setup a token cache, but not sure where from the above code sample, the token is generated and returned. I think it is stored in this variable on postback, Request.Form["id_token"] but unsure on how to store this in a cache/make it available for the entire application.

I have seen some examples that use Session Token Caches but if i am correct, this will require re auth to offcie 365 for each and every user and not be an app wide auth.

Ive tried searching for some samples or any pointers but cant seem to find any.

Anyone able to point me in the right direction

Comment: Im also having similar issue doing this with the MYOB API also.

Comment: If you are talking about accessing the API as an application (client credential flow), that's not about user authentication at all. You should not use id_token there, you have to use a bearer (access) token instead. And *Client credentials*  there -- are not the credentials of any administrator, these are the Id and validation key assigned to your application, and you can keep them in your config file. I suggest to read more about OAuth 2.0 / Open Id Connect basics.